# 1 Point Per $10

Tags: logic

I'm facing this problem where I need to give a user 1 point for every $10. For example:

```
$15 = 1 point
$23 = 2 points
$28 = 2 points
$33 = 3 points
```

I'm not good with math. Do you guys know the logic for this? Thanks

Comment: Divide by 10 and round down

Comment: can you give me the example ? just a simple code

Comment: I don't know PHP at all, but I'd hope you already know how to divide by 10. Then you just need to know how to round down, which is a simple thing to google

Comment: yeah already solved the problem , @abhishek-jain answer it , thanks for your help to rory-mccrossan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
$points = floor($price/10);
```

Comment: wow, works perfectly , thanks a lot sir , appreciate your help